Why my Delphi/11.3 Android application doesn't deploy files to TPath.GetDocumentsPath?
In my Delphi/Android application I try to use TIdHTTP. I deploy the .so files as in the screenshot below

and I set IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(TPath.GetDocumentsPath) but when I run it, I receive this error:

failed to load /data/user/0/com.embarcadero.TimApp/files/libcrypto.so

Searching my Android Tablet found nothing in the directory P25_T_EEA/Android/data/com.embarcadero.TimApp/files! This means that the .so files are not deployed, but in the file TimApp.deployproj exists this record:
<DeployFile Include="Android64\openssl-1.02_Android\armeabi-v7a\libcrypto.so" Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug'">
    <RemoteDir>TimApp\assets\internal\</RemoteDir>
    <RemoteName>libcrypto.so</RemoteName>
    <DeployClass>File</DeployClass>
    <Operation>0</Operation>
    <LocalCommand/>
    <RemoteCommand/>
    <Overwrite>True</Overwrite>
</DeployFile>
<DeployFile Include="Android64\openssl-1.02_Android\armeabi-v7a\libssl.so" Condition="'$(Config)'=='Debug'">
    <RemoteDir>TimApp\assets\internal\</RemoteDir>
    <RemoteName>libssl.so</RemoteName>
    <DeployClass>File</DeployClass>
    <Operation>0</Operation>
    <LocalCommand/>
    <RemoteCommand/>
    <Overwrite>True</Overwrite>

Please help me, I am stuck!
PS: is the directory P25_T_EEA/Android/data/  the same as /data/user/0/?

Do you have the StartUpCopy unit in your uses clause? It is supposed to copy deployed files from the app's internal storage to user folders where code can then access them

@RemyLebeau.Yes System.StartUpCopy is the first unit in program's uses clause. Also I set IdOpenSSLSetLibPath(TPath.GetDocumentsPath). Are the /data/user/0/com.embarcadero.TimApp/files/ and P25_T_EEA/Android/data/com.embarcadero.TimApp/files the same?
